# how to get the result of share in windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, share, windows-store-apps

When I share content to other Windows 8 apps, the share attempt may succeed or fail.  How do I determine what the result was?

For example, if I share an image, but due to format or image size constraints the target app cannot accept it, I want to detect the problem, resize the image then share the image again.

it occured errors, sometimes maybe the share target apps show a error msg, it said someting wrong and cannot share, when this case happens,

The problem is, how do I get that result?  If the share fails, how can my app detect the failure and get the reason it occurred?

I called all the methods within the "DataRequestedEventArgs" , but I didn't find this information returned by any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The share contract is not designed the way you're describing.

You can only provide the image data to the target app. Thats all you can do from your app. If the image size does not fit the requirements for the target application it would have to resize it itself.

Comment: But some apps doesn't limited the size of share image. If I resize the image the users won't share the original.

Comment: hi, @GameScripting, <br/>But some apps doesn't limited the size of share image. If I resize the image the users won't share the original<br/> My idea is when shared fail, the app automatically resize image and share the image again.<br/>As a general rule, I want to automatically share the original image

Comment: Your idea maybe useful but its technically **not possible**. The target application has to deal with the images as it comes in. If it's not able to do so contact the author of the target app so he/she can fix the issue.